# Postgres WHERE NOT IN taking a long time to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables `location` and `distance`

This query takes a **very** long time to execute:

```
SELECT source.name AS source, source.id AS source_id, dest.name AS destination, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source, location AS dest
WHERE (source.id, dest.id) NOT IN (
    SELECT source_id, destination_id FROM distance
)
```

Even `LIMIT 100` Takes >30 seconds to return results (Total results are ~15k)

The 2 queries individually run almost instantly:

```
SELECT source.name AS source, source.id AS source_id, dest.name AS destination, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source, location AS dest
```

and

```
SELECT source_id, destination_id FROM distance
```

Also, modifying the query with `EXCEPT` fixes the query runtime:

```
SELECT source.id AS source_id, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source, location AS dest
EXCEPT
SELECT source_id, destination_id FROM distance
```

But I want all the 4 columns, not the just 2.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`! [(reference)](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-exists/)

I just modified my query like:

```
SELECT source.name AS source, source.id AS source_id, dest.name AS destination, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source, location AS dest
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM distance
    WHERE source_id = source.id AND destination_id = dest.id
)
```

This runs instantly!

Big thanks *RhodiumToad* on *#postgres* IRC!

Turns you should **never** use `NOT IN`. Its in [Postgres' Don't do this:](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN)

> Don't use `NOT IN`, or any combination of `NOT` and `IN`
>   such as `NOT (x IN (select…))`.
>
> (If you think you wanted `NOT IN (select …)` then you should rewrite to
>   use `NOT EXISTS` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make use of an anti `left join`. Also, you want to use proper, explicit join syntax instead of old-school, implicit joins:

```
SELECT source.name AS source, source.id AS source_id, dest.name AS destination, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source
CROSS JOIN location AS dest
LEFT JOIN distance dist
    ON  dist.source_id = source.id 
    AND dist.destination_id = dest.id
WHERE dist.source_id IS NULL
```

For performance, consider the following indexes:

```
location(id)
distance(source_id, destination_id)
```

Finally: unless you do expect routes where the starting and ending point are the same, you can use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT source.name AS source, source.id AS source_id, dest.name AS destination, dest.id AS destination_id
FROM location AS source
INNER JOIN location AS dest
    ON source.id <> dest.id
LEFT JOIN distance dist
    ON  dist.source_id = source.id 
    AND dist.destination_id = dest.id
WHERE dist.source_id IS NULL
```